# Salesforce1 - Multiple Text Fields in Lightning Component causing page scrolling issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, salesforce1-app

Got a bit of a doozy involving the use of Lightning Components with more than 1 text field in Salesforce 1 using a Lightning Page, hoping someone can help.

The form in question has multiple text fields used for comments. The issue is when a user enters into more than one field, Salesforce appears to recalculate where it perceives to be the "top" of the page when scrolling.

What then happens is if a user wishes to scroll up, Salesforce treats this as a pull to refresh and the user loses all of the data. I have shifted this to a normal visualforce page and the issue is not present, however for performance reasons I'd like this to be a lightning page.

You can see a video of the issue here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9he95VOywDzYVdBUUVDWkxhdGc

Below is an image that describes the problem.

The issue:

- Happens on Android devices (multiple tested)
- Happens on iOS devices (multiple tested)
- Does not happen when using the dev user agent in Chrome (it is possible to force Salesforce1 and set the user agent to an Android / iOS device).

I have scoured the internet and SFDC issue tracker without much luck. StackExchange only lets me post one link with <10 karma but I also found on Salesforce issue tracker if you Google W-2747240

Any ideas?

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the Salesforce 1 app? Can you also confirm your Android version?

Comment: Yes latest version from the app store. Have also tested on an iPad and confirmed this happens on that as well. Android version 6.0.1.

Comment: After a fair bit of testing with emulators etc. I'm now sure this has to do with the virtual keyboarding, Salesforce seems to be redrawing the page height when the keyboard pops up and forgetting to recalculate it when the keyboard closes. Still not any closer to solving however..

Answer (score 1):

I've found a potential workaround for this issue. I had encountered the same bug and it seems to be present for me when you are trying to render the Lightning Component using a Lightning Page in Salesforce1. However, the Lightning Component works fine in Salesforce1 when you render it in a Visualforce Page using Lightning Out extension. The following link walks through an example of how to use Lightning Components in Visualforce pages:

- Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm

Even though the Lightning Component behaved as expected, unfortunately the performance of the page load wasn't as good as using a Lightning Page. It would be great to know if there's an actual fix to this!

Comment: Great value add Clint! Unfortunately the latency for visualforce pages is approx 6~8 seconds versus the 1-2~ seconds for lightning pages which makes a huge difference, as the lightning pages render client-side.

Comment: Yeah I understand that which is why I mentioned it as a drawback in the workaround. You could always add a load spinner to help mask the load times, but it would be even better if there was a fix for this!